# Delphi: Indy ContextClasses are created without clients connections

Tags: delphi, indy

I use TIdTCPServer in Delphi and sometimes it loads the CPU at 100% without any clients. This is due to the fact that constantly are created instances TIdContextClass. What should I do to correct it?

This is server code.

```
TMyTCPServer = class
private
  FTCPServer: TIdTCPServer;
  procedure ServerExecute(AIdContext: TIdContext);
public
  constructor Create();
  destructor Destroy(); override;
end;

{ TMyTCPServer }

constructor TMyTCPServer.Create;
begin
  try
    FTCPServer := TIdTCPServer.Create(nil);
    FTCPServer.OnExecute := ServerExecute;
    FTCPServer.DefaultPort := TServerSettingsSupport.Instance.Application_TCPConnectionPort;
    FTCPServer.ContextClass := TSServerContext;
    FTCPServer.Active := True;
  except
    on E: Exception do raise Exception.CreateFmt('Ошибка при подключениии к TCP-порту "%s"', [E.Message]);
  end;
end;

destructor TMyTCPServer.Destroy;
begin
  FTCPServer.Active := False;
  FreeAndNil(FTCPServer);
end;

procedure TMyTCPServer.ServerExecute(AIdContext: TIdContext);
begin
  //
end;

TSServerContext = class(TIdContext)
private
  FClientService: ISClientService;
  FStatFormer: IStatForm_ServerCallFullStat;

  procedure WaitingForData(out AWithoutResult: Boolean);
  procedure ContextExecute;
protected
  function Run: Boolean; override;
end;
```

Descendant class TContext

```
{ TServerThread }

procedure TSServerContext.ContextExecute;
var
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
  Mess, RMess: IAbstractMessage;
  Size: Integer;
  MDisp: TMessageDispatcher;
  WithoutResult: Boolean;
  isNeedBuffering: Boolean;
begin
  FClientService := TClientServiceFactory.CreateClientService;
  FStatFormer := TStatForm_ServerCallFullStat.Create();
  isNeedBuffering := TServerSettingsSupport.Instance.Application_NeedBufferingQueryResult; 

  MDisp := TMessageDispatcher.Create(FClientService);
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    try
      while Assigned( Connection ) and Connection.Connected do
      begin
        // Ждем первых данных сообщения. Периодически проверяем очередь
        // сообщений потока на сообщения завершения (WM_QUIT)
        WaitingForData(WithoutResult);

        FStatFormer.Start();
        Size := Connection.IOHandler.ReadInteger;

        // Новая активность клиента
        FClientService.NewActivity;

        Stream.Clear;
        Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(Stream,Size);
        Stream.Position := 0;

        Mess := TAbstractMessage.RestoreMessage(Stream);
        Stream.Clear;
        FStatFormer.FinishReadInputData(Mess.GetInstance().ClassName());
        RMess := MDisp.Process(Mess);
        FStatFormer.FinishProcessData();
        if not WithoutResult then
        begin
          TAbstractMessage.StoreMessage(RMess,Stream);
          if ((Stream.Size / 1024 / 1024) <= 60) and isNeedBuffering then
            Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferOpen;
          try
            Connection.IOHandler.Write(Stream,0,True);
          finally
            if Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferingActive then
              Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferClose;
            Stream.Clear;
            RMess := nil;
          end;
        end;
        FStatFormer.FinishWriteOutputData();
      end;
    except
      raise;
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
    MDisp.Free;

    FClientService := nil;
    FStatFormer := nil;
  end;
end;

function TSServerContext.Run: Boolean;
begin
  try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      ContextExecute;
      Result := True;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
  except
    on E: EIdSocketError do
    begin
      case E.LastError of
        Id_WSAECONNABORTED,
          Id_WSAECONNRESET:
          Connection.Disconnect;
      end;

      Result := False;
    end;

    on EIdClosedSocket do
    begin
      Result := False;
    end;

    on E: Exception do
    begin
      if E is EIdSilentException then
      begin
        raise;
      end
      else
      begin
        raise;
        Result := False;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TSServerContext.WaitingForData(out AWithoutResult: Boolean);
var
  dataReceived: Boolean;
  MSG: TMsg;
begin
  dataReceived := False;
  while (not dataReceived) do
  begin
    // Обрабатываем сообщения из очереди. Проверка на завершение.
    while (PeekMessage(MSG, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) do
    begin
      case (MSG.message) of
        WM_QUIT:
          begin
            Connection.Disconnect;
          end;
      end;
    end;

    Connection.IOHandler.ReadTimeout := cReadTimeout;
    try
      try
        AWithoutResult := Boolean(Connection.IOHandler.ReadInteger);
        dataReceived := True;
      except
        on E: EIdReadTimeout do
        begin
          // Таймаут - обрабатываем сообщение из очереди
        end;
      end;
    finally
      Connection.IOHandler.ReadTimeout := IdTimeoutInfinite;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Please show your server code.

Answer (score 1):

`TIdTCPServer` does not "constantly create context objects". It creates a context object
, waits for a client to connect, associates the two and runs a thread to manage them, then repeats.  Any error in that logic will kill the thread that is creating context objects and accepting clients.  So the only way `TIdTCPServer` can be utilizing so much CPU is if you have one or more runaway threads that are not yielding CPU time.  `TIdContext` is itself not a thread, it is merely used inside of a thread.  This kind of high CPU usage is most commonly caused by `OnExecute` code that is erroneously mishandling Indy error/exceptions and not letting `TIdTCPServer` handle them, causing an endless loop in the client thread instead of letting it terminate itself.

**Update**: your `OnExecute` event handler is empty.  That event is multithreaded and called in a loop for the lifetime of each client connection.  An empty handler causes each client thread to run a tight unyielding loop, which would account for your high CPU usage.  You MUST yield periodically.  In this case, your handler should be calling `TSServerContext(AIdContext).Run;`  The socket read operations will then perform the necessary yielding for you.

Comment: Maybe you right, but when one or two test clients connect to server, this problem doesn't rise. It rise only when ten and more test clients connect.

One test client makes more then 1000 queries.